# Power Point - Add-in (VSTO) , how to Make custom form not come out of Powerpoint

Tags: vb.net, vsto, powerpoint-addins

I am Working in A PowerPoint Add-in an VB.net (VSTO) Project , In that I have created an Custom form and from Add-in Ribbon when user click's it's opened with the below command

```
     Dim x = New Form_SendSlides()
        x.Show()
```

So now the problem is when power point is minized (or) focused out the custom form is still not minized and it's showing outside the Powerpoint as well.

I can't use ShowDailog as user need to make changes when form is opened in the backend.

So how to keep the custom form inside power point and how to handle the focus out and minized ? Need a solution for it

I Tried writing a custom on focus out for the Form , when the parent is not power point it must minize but , it's not working fine.

Simply it keep on closing if it's minimised